# TopStack - Android client for Stack Exchange

Tags: app, java, android

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
[image]

### About

Android client for Stack Overflow and then all Stack Exchange sites in the future.

#### License

Freeware. Will probably change to ad-supported or maybe open-source (depends on your requests).

#### Download

Link for android:
market://search?q=pname:org.topixoft.top_stack_overflow
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.topixoft.top_stack_overflow

QR code:
[image]

Cyrket:
http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/org.topixoft.top_stack_overflow/

#### Platform

Android devices.

### Contact

Leave comments for the app in Android Market, contact me through the market or leave comments here.

### Code

Uses:

- [Java/Android SDK](http://www.android.com/)
- [stackoverflow-java-sdk](http://code.google.com/p/stackoverflow-java-sdk/) -  I'm actively contributing to the project

The app is currently closed-source.

Comment: Change the name, you can't have "Stack overflow" in the name as it could confuse the users into thinking this is an official SO application

Comment: ...and the screenshot on the right looks remarkably similar to the main SO interface.

Comment: I don't want to seem condescending, but this is a low quality app, and my opinion is that you shouldn't have released to the Market. You'll only get low active/total install ratio and bad ratings. Also, viewing questions is defective -- code blocks appear on one line and one out of three questions don't load (browser error page).

Comment: The app is in rapid development, and I would like to see users suggesting things and finding bugs.
@Felix,@Matt thanks for your comments, I've already addressed some of the issues, keep them coming :)

Comment: This looks interesting, Vitaly. Could you also provide a download link for people who don't have access to Android Market? Regarding the license I'd recommend you to consider BSD (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php). Of course, others like the GPL are also options. If unsure you might wanna ask your preferred search engine regarding comparison.

Comment: @Vitaly Plonetsky: Is this application still maintained ? I just entered my comments on the market - with the advent of more and more aPads this program is really a very good example of a program for higher resolution screens.

Comment: It would be real great if it were open sourced :) Also, where can I download the .apk installer?

Comment: Would be nice if you could login into your own account and see just your own questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links to the source and install website went dead. I'm keeping this for reference in case someone else gets inspired by this and creates a new fresh script or app.